# Cytoscape: finding the leaves of a specific node

Tags: cytoscape.js

I suppose it is possible to find the leaves of a particular node.
The first line of my code works, the second returns an empty object {}

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

`console.log( cy.nodes().leaves().jsons() );
console.log( cy.nodes("[id='1.1']").leaves().jsons() );`

Answer (score 1):

Selectors can't have metacharacters, like `.`.  You need to escape them.  Refer to http://js.cytoscape.org/#selectors/notes-amp-caveats